# How to interpret the "Omega" symbol in $\Omega_{n=0}^\infty z_n=(z_0,z_1,z_2,\ldots)$?

Tags: calculus, notation

In some notes about complex number successions i came across this symbol Ω used in this unusual way and I do not know what it means.

[image]

It would be very helpful knowing how it works.

Thanks.

Edit 1: They're notes from a complex variable class, in which the purpose it's to define the concept and some considerations about the "complex number successions". The comment on the top uses a concept between the quotation marks, in which he tries to say that the very definition of those complex number successions it's something like a"infinite ordered pair". I didn't post the full of it 'cause is in mainly in spanish.

Thanks again.

[image]

Comment: Looks like it's just used to denote an infinite sequence (or perhaps infinite vector). It's hard to really guess without context though; even if one of those are correct, it wouldn't be a standard notation (or one that I've run into).

Comment: Hmmm, looks like it denotes a set.

Comment: Complex number successions => sequences of complex numbers?  Is there any more information to identify the "notes" where this notation appears?  If a set of class notes, which class was it?

Comment: $\Omega$ looks a little like $\prod$ (depending on handwriting) but that's not the standard usage of $\prod$

Comment: I would say what you show is the definition of the symbol.

Answer (score 1):

That is non-standard notation for an element of $\prod_{n=0}^\infty\mathbb C$. I.e.,
$$\Omega_{n=0}^{\infty} z_n \in \prod_{n=0}^\infty\mathbb C.$$

A more standard way to denote it would be $(z_n)_{n=0}^\infty\in\prod_{n=0}^\infty\mathbb C$.